# returning json data from php as response in javascript ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter-2

I'm building simple store website with codeigniter. and if user wanna buy product he must login as member 1st. the tasks i want to create when user click "buy" on product:

1. if user not login alert "please login 1st"
2. if stock product if empty alert "stock is empty"
3. if ok, then alert "product added to cart"

I have code like this:
cart.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //var url = window.location.pathname;
    var base = 'http://thita.dev/index.php/'
    //alert(url);
    $('.prod_box form').submit(function() {
        var id = $(this).find('input[name=id_produk').val();  
        var qty = $(this).find('input[name=qty]').val();

        //alert('ID:' + id + '\n\rQTY:' + qty);
        $.post(base + 'order/tambah_belanja', {id_produk: id, quantity: qty, ajax: '1'}, function(data) {
            if (data.status === true) {
                alert(data.message);
            } else {
                if (data.errtype === 'login') {
                    alert('please login 1st');
                } else if (data.errtype === 'stok') {
                    alert('Stock is empty');
                }
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

controller order.php:

```
public function tambah_belanja() {
    $this->load->library('auth');
    $data = array();

    if (!$this->auth->cek_login()) {
        $data['status'] = false;
        $data['errtype'] = 'login';
    }

    if ($this->mo_order->tambahBelanja() === TRUE) {
        if ($this->input->post('ajax') <> '1') {
            redirect('order');
        } else {
            $data['status'] = true;
            $data['message'] = 'product is added to cart';
        }
    } else {
        $data['status'] = false;
        $data['errtype'] = 'stok';
    }

    return json_encode($data);
}
```

module mo_order.php:

```
function tambahBelanja() {
    $id_produk = $this->input->post('id_produk');
    $qty = $this->input->post('quantity');

    $this->db->where('id_produk', $id_produk)
            ->where('stok >', 0);

    $Q = $this->db->get('produk', 1);

    if ($Q->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($Q->result() as $row) {
            $data = array(
                'id' => $row->id_produk, //id_produk
                'qty' => $qty, //qty
                'price' => $row->harga, //harga
                'name' => $row->nama_produk //nama_produk
            );
        }

        $this->cart->insert($data);
        file_put_contents('/tmp/data.txt', var_export(array('id_produk' => $id_produk, 'qty' => $qty, 'item' => $data), true));
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

when I try to run that codes, I still can add item to cart although I'm not login as member,  and the alert not show up.

how is the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
if (!$this->auth->cek_login()) {
        $data['status'] = false;
        $data['errtype'] = 'login';
    }else{ //Add this else here i.e if valid login

    if ($this->mo_order->tambahBelanja() === TRUE) {
        if ($this->input->post('ajax') <> '1') {
            redirect('order');
        } else {
            $data['status'] = true;
            $data['message'] = 'product is added to cart';
        }
    } else {
        $data['status'] = false;
        $data['errtype'] = 'stok';
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah, thanks guy it works, and in the javascript code parameter data which is json must be parsed 1st using parseJSON(). so it becomes var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data); . then we can use it, response.status, response.message, response.errtype

Comment: you can also specify the dataType option if you like